# How can I use cocoa pods to install google cloud messaging without firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-cloud-messaging

I have an existing `iOS application` which uses an earlier version of google cloud messaging before it was updated to firebase.  I am trying to install google cloud messaging again without the firebase update using `cocoa pods`, I have tried

```
pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging', '~> 1.2'
```

and then imported `#import "GoogleCloudMessaging.h"`  but this does not recognise the old methods used.

and I have tried `pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' , '~> 1.2'` 
but this won't even install.

Any help would be great as already wasted several hours on this

Comment: "and I have tried pod 'Google/CloudMessaging' , '~> 1.2' but this won't even install." try using the prerelease version of Cocoapods

Comment: Well, if you check the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) on how to Setup a GCM Client App on iOS, they recommend you to use Firebase because GCM is now migrating to FCM. So what can I help you is to check this [Google SDK using CocoaPods](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods) and this [tutorial](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2016/01/29/quickstart-google-cloud-messaging-ios/) if it can help you to install the cocoa pods without using Firebase.

Comment: I know how to implement GCM, but we aren't migrating to FireBase as it is out of scope.  I just need to get the old GCM library into my project before it used firebase?

Comment: How can I use the pre-release version of cocoa pods?